# Android - выполнять какое-либо действие при зажатой клавише

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток! Я снова с вами (так как забанили на стаке) :)

Я пытаюсь сделать небольшую игру, смысл в том, что, например, при зажатой клавише `←` на физической клавиатуре персонаж будет медленно двигаться влево.

Я пытался сделать это с помощью `KeyEvent`:

---

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) move_pers(x_coord--);
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

---

Но персонаж двигается влево только на одну координату за одно нажатие. Я пытался сделать это в цикле `while`, но при зажатой кнопке приложение зависало, а при отпущенной кнопке игра отвисала, а кoордината персонажа имела крайне высокое значение.
Вопрос: как мне заставить персонажа плавно двигаться при зажатой клавише (желательно без Thread.sleep())?

Comment: move_pers только изменяет координату, или и перерисовывает ?

Comment: Только изменяет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как и следует из названия, onKeyDown вызывается только один раз в момент нажатия кнопки. Что бы отловить "удержание" кнопки, нужно использовать [View.OnKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)

Comment: А можно как-нибудь использовать onKey(...), не используя его вместе с каким-нибудь View?
Я имею в виду просто написать в классе это

    `@Override
    public boolean onKey(...) {...}`

И чтоб была возможность использовать этот метод без привязки его к конкретному View.